# XML reading and parsing

Tags: java, xml

I have to read 500K rows from a xml file and have to parse that xml .The xml is of size 30 MB.
When we have perform that parsing it gives us Out Of memory Error . Is there anyway or mechanism that can be suggested

Comment: This question isn't helpful at all...some additional information is needed, esp. what parser is used (I assume some DOM parser - but I'm just guessing...)

Comment: How are you trying to read the file? Don't load the entire file into a DOM tree...

Comment: @gaurav  you should use saxparser to fast xml parsing than other parser ,and if outofmemoryError occured you have to change xml file ane reduce data because its needed more space than java heap size so its create prblm!!!

Comment: @Philipp What in this question is not useful to you . Also i have used both DOM and SAX to read the file , I have to read the file then do the transformation into PDF via FOP ... But it is giving me both OutOf Memory Error in both wats

Comment: Hey Jonas What is the issue do you have with this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) and [StAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX) approaches.

Answer (score 3):

- Use a SAX parser
- You are probably storing the parsed content in memory. This is not a good idea.

Comment: I have also used SAX and DOM parser and it also gives the OutOfMemory Error

Comment: Also i have used both DOM and SAX to read the file , I have to read the file then do the transformation into PDF via FOP ... But it is giving me both OutOf Memory Error in both ways

Comment: either don't store everything in memory, or increase the heap memory using -Xmx512m (for 512 MBs). SAX or StAX should be more lightweight because you'll have only one representation of the data in memory.

Comment: Yes i have tried with STax it works but now i Have to transform that into PDF which tool I have to use to transform into PDF